# Neo4j null pointer while running embedded HA instance within cluster

Tags: neo4j

I'm attempting to upgrade a system from 1.8 to 1.9.1 and getting error messages in my logs.

When running an embedded version of neo4j in a cluster with one or more standalone neo4j instances I get the below error in the logs over and over. The error only occurs when the embedded instance is the master. If it is a slave, it does not print these errors. The system seems to work just fine, but a job continues to run every few seconds and print this error message.

Any ideas?

```
[Server receiving-2] ERROR org.neo4j.kernel.ha.com.master.MasterServer:176 - Exception from Netty
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.neo4j.com.Server$ServerHandler.writeComplete(Server.java:337) ~[neo4j-com-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireWriteComplete(Channels.java:324) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.write0(AbstractNioWorker.java:275) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromTaskLoop(AbstractNioWorker.java:150) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioChannel$WriteTask.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:335) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:366) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this exception persists with Neo4j 1.9.3. There have been a significant number of fixes and improvements since 1.9.1.